# Show that the set $ \{0,1,2\} \times \mathbb{N} $ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Show that the set $ \{0,1,2\} \times \mathbb{N} $ is countable.I think that it is like the proof that $ \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable, am I right? or what is the right way of proving this?  could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: What is $\ast$?

Comment: @Hayden Cartesian product.

Comment: should $*$ be the $\times$ (`\times`) symbol?

Comment: It's more typical to use $\times$ for Cartesian product, just fyi. Think about it like this: you've got three copies of the natural numbers, tagged by $1,2,3$. The case of two copies of the natural numbers is like that of $\mathbb{Z}$ (one copy is $0,1,2,\ldots$, the second copy is $-1,-2,-3,\ldots$). If you think back to the argument you likely did for that, how can you extend that to three copies?

Comment: For the record, it is much easier than the proof that $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable. Both of them are easy to prove one you know how, but I would expect someone new to the subject to come up with a counting of $\{0,1,2\}\times \Bbb N$ on their own a lot faster and in fewer attempts than for $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f: \{0,1,2\} \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ as follows:

$$f(r,q) = 3q+r$$

I leave it as an exercise to you that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: why u choose this function exactly .... why 3q?

Comment: The inverse is actually the division algorithm... with $\{0,1,2\}$ being the possible remainders, and the divisor being naturally 3.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1,2\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^2\{(n,i):n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Thus $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1,2\}$ is countable as a finite union of countable sets.

Also for all $i \in \{0,1,2\}$ each set $A_i=\mathbb{N} \times \{i\}=\{(n,i):n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable

> Fix $i \in \{0,1,2\}$ and take the function $$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times\{i\}$$ $$n \mapsto (n,i)$$

It is not difficult to see that $f$ is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

An explicit enumeration of $\{0,1,2\}\times\mathbb N$:
$(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (0,3), (1,3), \ldots$

Here the first number in the pair counts $0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,\ldots$ and when it "wraps" from $2$ to $0$ the second number increases.

The enumeration corresponds to $f^{-1}$ with $f$ defined by Kenny Lau.